# More control over what is printed out when an exception is caught

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, printstacktrace

Is there a way to grab specific information from an exception when an exception occurs?

For example when I call `printStackTrace` I get a lot of information...but sometimes I get too much information and most of it is not things I need to see since it's always the same information anyways.

At least when it comes to Selenium Webdriver, it first tells me what the problem is

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element blah not found
  at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.ElementFinder.findElement(ElementFinder.java:92)
  at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Click.handleSeleneseCommand(Click.java:35)
  at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Click.handleSeleneseCommand(Click.java:1)
  at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.SeleneseCommand.apply(SeleneseCommand.java:35)
  at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Timer.run(Timer.java:40)
  at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:140)  
  ...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ...
...
...
...
```

And then it goes on to tell me things about the my environment, capabilities (with another list of messages), and more "caused by" information.

It's a pretty long message, and I don't want it cluttering my log file.
Is there a way to omit all of the "caused by" related messages?

I tried `getMessage` but it only says

```
Element blah not found
```

Which is not useful. I would like to at least see which line it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, get only the first few stack frames and parse them. Use `getStackTrace`to get a `StackTraceElement[]` and iterate through them until you get a frame in *your package*(or however else you want to filter) to get the correct line. The Selenium internal lines probably aren't the ones you need.

On this element you can call `getMethodName`, `getLineNumber`, and [the like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).